# Reactjs - Using "this" in components - should it be avoided at all times?

Tags: reactjs, this, state, flux, reactjs-flux

**In a nutshell**

After using React for a few months - the idea of using `this` to keep track of changing variables in a component has come to feel like snorkeling in the North Pole - no one should do it,ever.

But with Leaflet that is kind of what happens(and for details I'll skip, I can't use the really sweet leaflet component wrapper that now exist.

**The problem that lead me to `this`:**

**I'm trying to save the initial zoom level into a store as state**, but since I'm using an Action that changes the rendering path the opens the `Map Component` I can't call another Action as the `MapComponent` mounts without getting a chain Action error "Invariant Dispatch". I also couldn't find any async updates to zoom in the Leaflet Docs to get around the synchronous Actions error.

Without the initial zoom I can't see if the first zoom the user makes is up or down :(

**My Hack Solution:**

Since the rest of the map is saved in `this` I just created another property of `this` called `this.currenZoom` that gets initialized as the component mounts and updated when `zoomStart`is called.(technically updates like state)

**My Question:**

Am I snorkeling in the North Pole using `this` to keep my zoom state? Or is that acceptable since Leaflet technically isn't working with the virtual DOM the same way? **Is using `this` okay to manage variable updates in some cases in our components.**

**Note: This question might come of as peevish, but seriously I've went so long using `state` and `props` for everything that it just feels MEGA hacky using `this` in my components.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do think it's fine to keep data directly on `this` **if and only if it doesn't affect rendering** (although I wouldn't do so unless there's a good reason not to simply put it in the component's state). The `render` method should *always* be a function of `this.state` and `this.props` (and *only* those two things).

Doing this is most often used as an "escape hatch" mechanism--like the scenario you mention here--where some library, plugin, or function doesn't interact with the virtual DOM in the same way as a normal component.

You can even see the React documentation using this method [in the `SetIntervalMixin` mixin example](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#mixins):

```js
var SetIntervalMixin = {
  componentWillMount: function() {
    this.intervals = [];
  },
  setInterval: function() {
    this.intervals.push(setInterval.apply(null, arguments));
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.intervals.forEach(clearInterval);
  }
};
```

Comment: This is a solid answer! Thank you @MichelleTilley